# Feed can show entries for deleted posts, which viewing them fails

Tags: bug, android-app, deleted-questions, android-app-feed

Just noticed this:

Someone @replied to me in a question which appropriately showed up in my feed.

I go to *click* on that notice in the feed, and it presents me with "Loading the question failed."

I'd show a picture, but I don't think that it's entirely relevant - I believe it's reproducible if an answer is posted, someone makes a reply, the answer is removed, then that someone else goes back in the feed to try and revisit the post.

Alternatively, why not synchronize the interface between what a 10K user sees on the site, and what they see in the app?  As a 10K user, I would expect to see deleted questions and answers.

Comment: Please fix this annoying feature.