# Inconsistent behavior between desktop site and android app regarding comments on deleted posts

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

Earlier today, a diamond mod deleted (an already closed) [question I had on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272555/2422776). He also left a comment explaining the rationale behind the deletion and encouraged me to flag the post for his attention in case I disagree with the deletion.

On the desktop site I got a notification about a new comment, and since I have more than 10K reputation on SO (and thus also on MSO), I was able to click through and see the comment.
On the other hand, on the android app I also got the notification, but when I clicked through, I got an error message "The question is not available, it may have been deleted".

If this post is generally available to me, shouldn't it also be available on the app?
Alternatively, perhaps the comment shouldn't be clickable on the app?

Technical details:

- App version: 1.0.95
- Android version: 8.0.0
- Phone mmode: Samsug Galaxy S8

Comment: Related, or dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194897 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229194 (in short: it's an API limitation)